# Excel If formula not evaluating correctly?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an IF formula that is evaluating two cells with data returned from other formulas.

=IF(B5>D5,D5,B5)

Seems simple enough, right? However, when I attempt to use it, it seems to be evaluating the formulas in the cells instead of evaluating the values being returned.

I.E.: If B5 returns 414 and D5 returns 416, I get 416 instead of 414.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your formula appears to be OK. Must be something else with your spreadsheet. Let's say cell B5 contained the formula `=413+1` and D5 contained `=417-1`. If I put your formula in a different cell than these, it evaluates to 414, as expected.

Comment: I was also unable to reproduce. I created two cells and put text numbers in them `'414` and `'416` then I create two new cell formulas pointing to those. I did the inequality test against both the original cells and the formula versions and the expected results was returned.

Comment: Would you happen to have your calculations set to manual? Just for fun, hit F9 and see if the formula spits out what you expect? That's a long shot, but I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too. No change. It even shows the numbers in the cells when I open the Formula Arguments window. It actually shows me that it selected 416 over 414!

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, your formula worked for me.  Are you trying to display the lower number of the cells?  If so, try this

```
=MIN(B5,D5)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `MIN`, but perhaps it would help if you mentioned *what* you tested, i.e. what exactly you put in B5 and D5. (I know that in theory it shouldn't matter, but for completeness' sake...)

Comment: =MIN() does not work either. The cells contain results of VLOOKUP formulas.

Comment: Even with VLOOKUP's in my testing, I still get MIN to work.  Can you give us more details on what your VLOOKUP formulas look like?

Comment: Sure. =VLOOKUP(Report!A8,Enc!$A$1:$B$34,2,FALSE) in B5 and =SUM(E6:F6) in D6.

Comment: I've remember having run into a similar, weird problem with `VLOOKUP` in the past. I cannot remember the details, but it has led me to avoid `VLOOKUP` if I can help it, because I got the impression that it doesn't always work reliably. I'm looking forward to seeing whether you can resolve this.

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?  I'm using 2010 and can't seem to replicate your issue, but would like to keep looking into it.

Comment: I'm using 2010. The issue is with VLOOKUP. If I use any other formula or number, the IF statement works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

While checking out my VLOOKUP formulas in the calculator I found an interesting fact. VLOOKUP returns all answers as text. So, in order to use the numerical value, place the cell inside the VALUE() function.

=IF(VALUE(B5)>D5,D5,VALUE(B5))

Voila! Works now!

Alternatively, you can place the VLOOKUP inside the VALUE function.

Thanks for your help guys!